# Rails double render error even when returning on both renders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm seeing a double render error on rails even when I include the 'and return' after the render call. Strange thing is it doesn't seem to happen in development, even though both rails versions are the same in prod and dev.

```
    if !existing_installation
      if new_auth_flow? 
        start_auth_flow
        render(:front_end_redirect, layout:false) and return
      else
        complete_oauth_flow
      end
    end

    if plan.blank?
      render(:billing_confirmation_url_redirect) and return
    end
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: To rule out any precedence errors I tried moving 'and return' to the next line so it's just

```
render(:front_end_redirect, layout:false)
return
```

but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @dbugger I doubt its really down to `&&` vs `and` preceedence. If I was a gambling man I would put my money on that ithat a callback for example is rendering/redirecting and not properly halting the execution chain and that the lack of parity between dev/production is due to deficient tests and methodology issues.

Comment: To actually be able to debug this code however we need enough context for this code to be a reproducable example and we also need to see the incoming request. An integration test covering the different pathways would also be very useful.

Comment: @max I think you're right that there was a render in a method that was getting called. how would you normally call 'render' from a private method in a parent class? Should the 'render' be in the main controller action instead?

Comment: Its not really about the render call - if you want to bail and halt further execution you can use `throw(:abort)` - if you're returning from a private method it doesn't actually do anything besides halt execution of that specific method.